# Flutter autocomplete widget errortext pushes options down

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete

I am making an android app with flutter that keeps track of expenses(at the request of my mom), I am having issues implementing the autocomplete widget.

Autocomplete normally looks like this(these are just placeholder categories for now):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv7N3.png)

But there is input validation, one of the probems is that it pushes down the widgets below like this:
[without errortext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZCOe.png), [with errortext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgxZc.png)

I can kinda fix it by making the sized box the autocomplete is in bigger, but then the options get pushed down like this, which looks really stupid:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7giWu.png)

The other problem is that the error text does the same. like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcBx1.png)

Relevant code:

```
SizedBox(
  width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*(0.8)),
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) => Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Material(
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(10), top: Radius.circular(10)),
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)), color: const Color.fromARGB(100,220,220,220)),                            
            height: 52.0 * min(5, options.length),
            width: constraints.biggest.width,
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              itemCount: options.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final String option = options.elementAt(index);
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () => onSelected(option),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(option),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        return maincategories.where((String entry)  {
          if (textEditingValue.text.length > entry.length) {return false;}
          else {
            return textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase() == entry.substring(0, textEditingValue.text.length).toLowerCase();
          }
          });
      },
      fieldViewBuilder: (context, textEditingController, focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) {
        return TextField(
          focusNode: focusNode,
          controller: textEditingController,
          onEditingComplete: onFieldSubmitted,
          decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)), 
            fillColor: Colors.white, filled: true, hintText: "Select main category",
            errorText: _errorText1(maincategories, textEditingController),
            contentPadding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*(0.025)),
              horizontal: 10),),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: You already added a label maybe that's why the error text can't be a label.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextField` is working fine if we hide `errorText`.
[image]

You've already something in the below(`optionsBuilder`), maybe that's why the `errorText` pushed down the others.

**Tip:** I hope you can try to add your `errorText` in the `labelText/label` as `errorText` to look good. You can also add `style` for `errorText/LabelText`.